# How to detect link Android device is visiting in its browser and send the url to another app?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I want to create an app to detect fraud/phishing links, this app acts as an overlay over browsers, how do I read the website the browser is visiting and send it to the app so that I can send the url for analysis to the backend.

How do I read the url from the mobile browser exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

That works fine for me.

As for the missing "http://" I'd just do something like this:

```
if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
   url = "http://" + url;
```

I would also probably pre-populate your EditText that the user is typing a URL in with "http://".